# google app engine python as backend and angular js as frontend for mobile web

Tags: python, json, angularjs, google-app-engine, mobile

I m trying to implement end to end data sharing between GAE via python and angularJS mobile app using JSON as request body from mobile with contentType as application/json.
I can see in my log that GAE is receiving data and sending a response i.e. `{'status': true}`.

My Firebug console shows red font(error) for POST request to my GAE server but response status is 200 (ok). Mobile app is getting a 200 status of response but does not get the data.

In my mobile app I'm using `$http.post(url, data);` to make an http request to GAE and I get this in my Firebug console:

```
POST http://<code>serverAddress_is_localhost_for_testing</code>:8080/serviceProvider

200 OK
23ms
```

In the GAE log I can see that the data is processed correctly. This is response code for Python:

```
self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
self.response.out.write(response)
```

Comment: Is the mobile app hosted on a different (sub)domain than the backend? If so - [see more on CORS here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: yes the domains are different, but i can see in the logs of my server that the request is successfully computed and response is sent to my mobile client app. status 200 of HTTP POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

**`self.response.headers.add_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")`**

before

`self.response.out.write(response)`

If that works, replace "*****" with your angular/mobile app's domain.

[Read more on Cross-origin resource sharing here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Comment: "If that works, replace "*" with your angular/mobile app's domain"   actually the mobile client currently(testing only) is served from localhost, but in actual it will be a cordova mobile app.